# Find Next function in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make 'find/find next' function in my windows store application.
Word which I want to search and select is in textBox named 'tboxFind'.
Textbox 'EditorWindow' contains all my text.

My function works good only if there is one line of text in 'editorWindow'. 
Otherwise, selection is moved forwards by number of new lines.

How to fix it?

Is there any simple way to create find next function?

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((tmpPos) == pos && tmpWord == tboxFind.Text && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(editorWindow.Text))
    {
        string tmpString = editorWindow.Text.Substring(pos + tboxFind.Text.Length);
        tmpPos = tmpString.ToLower().IndexOf(tboxFind.Text.ToLower());
        if (tmpPos != -1)
        {

            editorWindow.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Keyboard);
            editorWindow.SelectionStart = pos + tmpPos + tboxFind.Text.Length;
            editorWindow.SelectionLength = tboxFind.Text.Length;
            pos = pos + tmpPos + tboxFind.Text.Length; 
        }
    }
    tmpWord = tboxFind.Text;
    tmpPos = pos;
}
```

// EDIT:
I found a different way to create that function.  Here is my code:

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        numOfNewLines = 0;


            pos = (tmpWord == tboxFind.Text) ? editorWindow.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(tboxFind.Text, pos + tboxFind.Text.Length) 
                                             : editorWindow.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(tboxFind.Text);
            if (pos != -1)
            {
                foreach (char s in editorWindow.Text.Substring(0, pos))
                {
                    if (s == '\n')
                    {
                        numOfNewLines++;
                    }
                }
                pos -= numOfNewLines;
                editorWindow.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Keyboard);
                //tmpPos = editorWindow.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(tboxFind.Text);
                editorWindow.Select(pos, tboxFind.Text.Length);
                pos += numOfNewLines;

            }
            tmpWord = tboxFind.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what's wrong with your code because I can't fully replicate it, but consider the following SSCCE in a basic Windows application:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);

        foreach (var i in FindIndicies("text"))
        {
            this.textBox1.SelectionStart = i;
            this.textBox1.SelectionLength = "text".Length;

            var result = MessageBox.Show(
                "Move to the next index?",
                "Next?",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No) { break; }
        }
    }

    private List<int> FindIndicies(string textToFind)
    {
        var indicies = new List<int>();
        var offset = 0;
        var i = 0;

        while ((i = this.textBox1.Text.IndexOf(
            textToFind,
            offset,
            StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) > 0)
        {
            indicies.Add(i);
            offset = (i + textToFind.Length);
        }

        return indicies;
    }
}
```

given that `textBox1` has a set text value of:

```
Here is a set of text
and I'm going to find the word text

Even when there are multiple lines of text.
```

It finds each index properly, and selects them properly.

I would consider finding all indicies up front with the method I wrote and then simply iterate through them on demand. In my case I'm using a message box to determine when I want to move to the next index, but you'll use something different.